# Expression for the Lee form

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras

On a Hermitian manifold $(M,J,g)$ with associated fundamental form $\omega(X,Y)=g(JX,Y)$ we have an $L^2$ inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ on $p$-forms $\alpha,\beta$ given by integrating $\alpha \wedge * \beta$ where $*$ denotes the Hodge star operator and we define $d^*$ as the adjoint of the differential $d$ with respect to $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$. I have read many places now two equivalent definitions of this so-called Lee-form $\theta$:

1. $\theta$ is the unique 1-form such that $d\omega^{n-1}=\theta \wedge \omega^{n-1}$ where $\omega^{n-1}$ denotes the $(n-1)$-fold wedge product of $\omega$ with itself, $2n=\text{dim}(M)$.
2. $\theta=J(d^*\omega)$ where $J$ acts on 1-forms $\beta$ as $(J\beta)(X)=-\beta(JX)$.

My question is: Why do these two definitions of $\theta$ define the same object, or at least why does the expression for $\theta$ in 2. satisfy the relation in 1.? I've found and proved concrete expressions for $d$ and $d^*$ in terms of the interior product operator and Levi-Cevita connection, so I thought that I should be able to simply compute the relevant quantities, in say an orthonormal frame $e_1,...,e_{2n}$ for which $\omega=e^1 \wedge e^{2n}+\cdots+e^n \wedge e^{n+1}$ where $e^i$ denotes the dual of $e_i$. Considering that both forms in 1. are $2n-1$ forms I thought it should not be that difficult to actually verify 1. given 2., but I don't seem to gain anything usefull from my computations, especially considering that I don't have a nice expression for $\omega^{n-1}$. Is there a better way to go about this than simply direct computation, maybe using some properties of the operators involved instead? Any hints or suggestions as to how I could proceed will be very much appreciated as I seem to be stuck at the moment. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I got it actually, so I'll post an answer for future reference or in case it might be usefull for other people at some point:
The co-differential $d^*$ on a Hermitian manifold satisfies $d^*=-*d*$ and $*$ is an isometry, so in particular injective. It can also be checked that $\omega^{n}=n!\text{Vol}$ where $\text{Vol}$ is the Riemanian volume form. Hence identity 1. is equivalent to $\frac{1}{n!}d^*\omega=-*(\theta \wedge \omega^{n-1})$. Also, we can pick a basis $e^1,...,e^{2n}$ for which $\theta=ae^1$ and $\omega=e^1 \wedge e^2+\cdots+e^{2n-1}\wedge e^{2n}$ (so we take $e^2=Je^1,e^4=Je^3,...$). Using the fact that 2-forms commute one can be convinced that $*(\theta \wedge \omega^{n-1})=\frac{1}{a(n-1)!}e^2=\frac{1}{a^2(n-1)!}J\theta$ and so with an appropiate choice of $a$ we see that 1. and 2. are in fact equivalent.